# ServiceStack OAuthProvider for Twitter API 1.1

Tags: c#, servicestack, twitter-oauth

I have a problem when I try to use the ServiceStack TwitterAuthProvider  I got the following exception:

> The remote server returned an error: (410) Gone.

It's supposed that this issue is caused because the twitter [API version for 1.0 is deprecated](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1) but I have no Idea where to start when doing my own implementation to support the version 1.1, I'd like some advice of how to proceed using the [OAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/Auth/OAuthProvider.cs?source=cc)

the site [social boostrap API](http://bootstrapapi.apphb.com/) site doesn't work when you try to login with twitter.

[image]

thanks